# Twitter returns [code] => 89 I just trying to use second time the tookens

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi im using this code for getting the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`

```
require 'autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));
echo $url;
header('Location: '.$url);
```

and on my call back url it is:

```
$request_token = [];
$request_token['oauth_token'] = $_REQUEST['oauth_token'];
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = 'JeVDKh0rSfBozrJ65p1lG4HaDmBtLkqF';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_REQUEST['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
$add = "INSERT INTO users SET 
        name = '".$user->name."',
        username = '".$user->screen_name."',
        oauth_token = '".$_REQUEST['oauth_token']."',
        oauth_token_secret = '".$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']."',
        oauth_verifier = '".$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']."',
        id_string = '".$user->id_str."',
        status = '1' ";
```

but when after that from database when i try to login it gives me

```
[code] => 89
[message] => Invalid or expired token.
```

on every access token im getting this error. i'm using this code for relogin

```
$oauth_token = 'token from db';
$oauth_token_secret = 'token_secrete from db';
$oauth_verifier = 'aoth verifier from db that i stored';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret );
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $oauth_verifier ));
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

Please help me whats the issue with my code. I have read tw don't expire the access token. so whats wrong with my current scenario..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually assigning `access_token_secret` as they are generated. First, inside your callback you may wish to add an expression just in case the `oauth_token` given in URL doesn't same with saved `oauth_token` on session on the time you're doing a request.

```
if ($_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
    echo 'Oauth token does not match!';
    exit();
}
```

Assuming they're match, now, create a connection with `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` that stored on session.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,  $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Above connection is only created for verifying your access token. Now, verify it with `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']` that appears on your callback URL param.

```
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
```

Afterward, your access token has now verified. You may store it to session (overwrite session beforehand or create a new one) or to database as you do.

```
//Verified access token
$oauth_token = $access_token['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

As it's been verified, now you should create another connection to playing around with. Just like what you do, looking up account's credentials.

```
$newConnection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$user = $newConnection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$add = "INSERT INTO users SET 
        name = '".$user->name."',
        username = '".$user->screen_name."',
        oauth_token = '".$oauth_token."',
        oauth_token_secret = '".$oauth_token_secret."',
        id_string = '".$user->id_str."',
        status = '1' ";
```

Notice that I remove `oauth_verifier` as you don't need it. The use of it is only to verify unverified access token, just like you create a new request for the first time.

And last, you may follow last snippet to open another connection from access token that stored on database.

```
$oauth_token = $row['oauth_token_from_db'];
$oauth_token_secret = $row['oauth_token_secret_from_db'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
```

Comment: Sir, this is issue is last snippet to open another connection from access token that is stored in db. but it always gives error to me. :(

Comment: You need to rewrite your callback as I post. Have you did it?